# Get a Property value in a BindingSource LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datasource, bindingsource

Below is my bindingSource.

```
pics_Data_HistoryBSForCounts.DataSource = from dh in dataCtx.Pics_Data_Histories
                                                        join ui in dataCtx.User_Infos on dh.User_Id equals ui.user_id into ui_dh
                                                        from ui_dh1 in ui_dh.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                        where dh.Changed_Date >= fromDate && dh.Changed_Date <= toDate
                                                        group ui_dh1 by ui_dh1.user_name into grouped
                                                      select new { UserName = grouped.Key.Trim(), Count = grouped.Count(a => a.user_name != null), UserID = grouped.FirstOrDefault().user_id };
```

I want to get the UserID of the current record.

```
var userRecord = pics_Data_HistoryBSForCounts.Current;
```

I get the current records as a string. Is there any way to get a property value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`BindingSource.Current` is an `object`. You can cast it to type T of you `IQueryable<T>` (dataCtx.Pics_Data_Histories). But that is an anonymous type, so it is easier to use a named type for it (otherwise you can only use Reflection to extract a property value).

So, suppose you have a class `UserData` (with `UserName`, `Count` and `UserID`). The `select` part of your query is:

```
select new UserData { UserName = grouped.Key.Trim(), ...
```

And the cast:

```
var userRecord = (UserData)pics_Data_HistoryBSForCounts.Current;
```